# How to set yarn.app.mapreduce.am.command-opts for spark yarn cluster job

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

I am getting "Container...  is running beyond virtual memory limits" error while running spark job in yarn cluster mode.
It is not possible to ignore this error or increase Vmem Pmem ratio.

Job is submitted through spark-submit with " --conf spark.driver.memory=2800m".
I think it is because default value of yarn.app.mapreduce.am.command-opts is 1G, so yarn kills my driver/AM as soon as my driver/AM uses more than 1G memory.

So I would like to pass "yarn.app.mapreduce.am.command-opts" to spark-submit in bash script. Passing it with "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions" errors out with "Not allowed to specify max heap(Xmx) memory settings through java options"

So how do I pass it ?

EDIT: I cannot edit conf files as that will make the change for all MR and spark jobs.